Any faster way to do this operation which loops for 16k times in c/c++
This code reduces a unsigned 32 bit integer into a 8bit as per our requirement.
Currently this operation takes almost 2.1 mili sec to complete. Can it be optimized to complete at least under 0.9 mili sec.
Currently running it on an embedded system running on Arm Cortex-A53
#define BUFFER_SIZE 0x10000
#define POSTBIN_BUFF_SIZE 0x4000

#define     MOD_VAL              0x3FFF
#define     BINNING              256     
#define     RESOLUTION           MOD_VAL+1

uint8_t *local_buff = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
uint32_t *buffer = (uint32_t *)malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);

for (int index = 0; index < POSTBIN_BUFF_SIZE; index++)
{
      mod_val = (buffer[index] & MOD_VAL);
      local_buff[index] = ((mod_val * BINNING) / RESOLUTION);
}

I tried to do a right shift operation instead of division(RESOLUTION), but it only increased the time of operation instead of reducing it.

Check the (optimized) compiler output, e.g. at Compiler Explorer. Perhaps your compiler does all proposed munging on itself, or some other compiler gives a hint how to persuade yours to generate faster code.

((mod_val * BINNING) / RESOLUTION) doesn't do what you think, since RESOLUTION is a macro that expands to an unparenthesized expression. It actually calculates (((mod_val * 256) / 0x3FFF) + 1)

@RaymondChen Thank You for pointing that out, I modified it to (RESOLUTION) now.

@njuffa I am using aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc with some library specific flags, but hadn't used any of optimization flags which u mentioned, -O3 -mtune=cortex-a53 worked best for me, now I am getting the operation done in almost 0.2 mili sec. Thank you Can you please post your comment so i can mark the answer as accepted

try
for (int index = 0; index < POSTBIN_BUFF_SIZE; index++)
{
    // uint32_t mod_val = (buffer[index] & MOD_VAL);
    // local_buff[index] = ((mod_val * BINNING) / RESOLUTION);
    local_buff[index] = (buffer[index] & MOD_VAL) >> 6;
}

